# ADF: Linked Service Connecting, to Blob storage, but cannot look a the specific file path

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

Using ADF, I've created a linked service to a Blob Storage on Azure.
The connection to the linked service works:
[image]

I added a file to the Blob storage which I can clearly see.
The Blob is defined with the Firewalls and Virtual Networks setting of "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses".

When I test the connection, it passes the test.
When I try to Browse the folder (it can see the folder!) to the specific file path I get error 403: Forbidden
[image]

I've tried adding permissions but to no avail.
The ADF has a Read permissions access (I'm talking about the SOURCE file here) to the container.
I've also tried adding all the IP addresses of the ADF region (Australia-East).
The Virtual Network is added and all the IP addresses behind which the ADF might sit are also whitelisted for the Blob storage.

Edit: the Data Factory is whitelisted for the blob storage:
[image]

and the access is done based on the System Assigned Managed Identity.

The one thing which I know works, but I don't want to do, is simply to enable access to this blob storage from ANY network.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to solve this issue as follows:

1. I created a separate integration runtime, using Azure, and enabeled the Managed Viuutal Network in it (instead of the AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime)
2. I created a private endpoint. Both steps were done as described in this document:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private#create-a-managed-private-endpoint
   I didn't miss any step, including the approving of the private endpoint to the said blob storage.
   That actually let to a different version of the 403 error.
3. Once done, I've edited the linked service to use the Authentication type of Account Key (and *not* of System Assigned Managed Identity).

[image]

And now I can look at the data in the folder:

[image]

And no more error 403

Answer (score 0):

To make successful connection follow below steps:

1. Add ADF’s managed identity into Storage accounts with proper access rights.
   Go to **Access control (IAM)** in your storage account >> **Add** >> **Add role assignment**. For a Role we select `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to your data factory managed identity (service principal) which is name of data factory.

[image]

2. Enable `Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account` setting on storage properties.

[image]
3.  Change authentication method from account key to managed identity.

[image]

Comment: Hi, all these steps mentioned in your answer are DONE, which is why I can access the linked service. It returns successful connection and I can see that there's a folder. It's when I click on the folder and try to browse the data and look at the specific file which is there that I get the error 403.

Comment: Can you add image where you get the erroe?

Comment: The image is added above, it's when I "Browse" the file path.